# Postgres SQL How to split and map two array columns into separate columns

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Table has 2 array columns Key and Value.
For EG:

| ID | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c,d | 1,2,3,4 |
| 2 | b,c | 7,8 |
| 3 | a,c | 0,9 |
| 4 | b,c,d | 3,7,1 |

Need to map the Key to the Value and split it into separate columns

| ID | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 |  | 7 | 8 |  |
| 3 | 0 |  | 9 |  |
| 4 |  | 3 | 7 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert both string into arrays, unnest the arrays and aggregate those key/value pairs back into a JSON value. That value then can be used to extract the four keys again:

```
select id, 
       cols ->> 'a' as a,
       cols ->> 'b' as b,
       cols ->> 'c' as c,
       cols ->> 'd' as d
from (
        select id, 
               (select jsonb_object_agg(k,v)
                from unnest(string_to_array(key,','), 
                            string_to_array(value, ',')) as x(k,v)) as cols
        from the_table        
) x
order by id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/7qM-VjSN)

I would probably create a function to make the code a bit easier to read.